# What happens when I add the .cpp file with the main function as source to the static library when compiling?

Tags: c++

I would imagine it would be compiled into the lib itself, but could not be called since there is no header for that main function? I recently did a project and I did that but it worked fine. Could not really find anything on the relationship between a compiled lib and a main function, whether one should include it or not, or if it is included what does it mean.

My project structure is:

```
src
   /main.cpp
   /etc.hpp and cpp
tests
     /main.cpp
     /unittest_x.cpp
```

Comment: Then main function does not need a header file to be called (in fact it's illegal for your program to call the main function). It perfactly OK for a main function to go in a library. It will be found there in just the same way as any other function.

Comment: But it can be called? I was under the assumption that the main function then could not be called and should not be called either. Will the static lib even execute the main function?

Comment: None of that is true, not sure where you are getting your information from. I can think of two different products which include a library containing a main function. It's not common, but it's perfectly OK to do.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514935/why-does-static-library-contain-a-main-function Will it be called? Well, a static lib is not executable, but you can link it to an executable and yes, then that main function will be called. Note: `main()` is defined to be in global scope, so linking any other lib or object files that also define main will yield a linker error.

Comment: @flowit The project I mentioned I linked my code as a static lib to gtest, which has its own main, but could still link it. How come?

Comment: A static lib on it's own it not executable. I am assuming that you will link the library containing the main function into an executable.

Comment: @Broccholio gtest is one of the products I was thinking of. You cannot link a static lib to another static lib and get an executable program. That's true whether or not the library has a main function. Libraries are not executable code, with main or without.

Comment: I built my unittests normally, not as a static lib i think. This is the cmake line i used:
target_link_libraries(${BINARY} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_lib gtest)
and there is a main.cpp in my unittests, which calls RUN_ALL_TESTS(), but the lib i compiled from my source has a main.cpp too. But it still works. How come then?

Comment: @Broccholio gtest is a special case. Their library provides a `main()` function which implements running their default testrunner. It's at least configurable with gtest, if you want to use their implementation or provide your own. That's because usually you'll test other libraries using gtest (and their test runner), while these are part of the build for a final executable,and shouldn't provide a `main()` themselves.

Comment: @Broccholio If your code has a main, then the linker will use that in preference to the one in gtest, if your code does not have a main then the one in gtest will be used. I'm not sure where your confusion is. main is just a function that the linker is looking for, much like any other function.

Comment: @Broccholio You should really mention all that information about gtest and your project structure in your question. That's very important. As mentioned that's a special case, and you'll get better answers what's necessary to do to setup that stuff correctly. I am taking  I am affording to add the gtest tag to your question as a start.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In what sense is gtest a special case? The linker isn't making any special treatment of it.

Comment: @john Insofar, that I can read from the comments that the OP struggles with getting the setup right. And that's specific for gtest. Unlike other libraries it's not intended to be linked with the final artifacts for example.

Comment: Well now that we know it is about googletest, this link is appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609265/gtest-cmake-multiple-definition-of-main gtest is special (compared to other libs) in so far, that it actually comes with its own main function.

Comment: My setup is working fine, I'm just confused when to provide a main in the library, and if it is a valid thing to do so. But seems like from the answers so far, it is, but what is the use case? So far I thought libraries can be used through headers, and if you add them to your project you can use the functionality. I dont get how does a library with a main functions, how would one use it. Gtest is just an example, i was using it when the question came up. Could be any other lib.

Comment: @flowit the post you linked before about lib containing main cleared it up a little bit.

Comment: So i  Edited the post with my folder structure. I create a static lib with the stuff in the src folder, including my main.cpp with the main funct. Then i compile the uinit tests by linking that  library, and adding the tests/main.cpp and unittest_cpps to the target, but it still compiles, which seems confusing, since the lib i created has main.cpp and the tests has one too.